# Detect when a chrome page has finished launching

Tags: c#, google-chrome, process, html

I am building an app that opens a web page in chrome, using this line

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", url);
```

I want to know (from C#) when that web page has finished loading.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: From what I know, you cant know when the page has been fully loaded by using C#... you have to use JS

Comment: if you need to inform your c# app, then you could host a webservice and call it from JS in the dom ready event

Comment: I know that the Chrome tab (which contains the page that I've opened) has associated a process that I can analyze from C#. That process should contain the information that I need, correct?